# How do I call the parent classes constructor with its original parameters in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have this code:

```
class A {
  var $arr = array();

  function __construct($para) {
    echo 'Not called';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  function __construct() {
    $arr[] = 'new Item';
  }
}
```

And as B has its own constructor construct($para) of A never gets called.

Now I could call parent::__construct($para) but then class B would need to be aware of the parameters class A needs.

I would prefer this:

```
class A {
  var $arr = array();

  function __construct($para) {
    echo 'Not called';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(); // With the parameters class B was created.

    // Additional actions that do not need direct access to the parameters
    $arr[] = 'new Item';
  }
}
```

Would something like that work?

I don't like the fact, that all classes that extend class A would need to define a new constructor, once class A changes its parameters, where all I want them to do is call the constructor of class A like when class B does not overwrite it with an own __construct() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to not override the parent constructor in the first place. Instead, define a separate (initially-empty) `init()` method that the parent constructor calls automatically. That method could then be overwritten in the child in order to perform the extra processing.

```
class A {
    public function __construct($para) {
        // parent processing using $para values

        // ..and then run any extra child initialization
        $this->init();
    }
    protected function init() {
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected function init() {
        // Additional actions that do not need direct access to the parameters
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that looks like what I was searching for. Thank you!

Comment: I've been using this approach in a project extensively and while it certainly works, I never liked it much because it somewhat reinvents constructors. It turns your objects into some kind of Base object and that hampers reuse.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to do this almost exactly like you originally described it, by using the [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) functions:

```
class B extends A {
    function __construct() {
        // call the parent constructor with whatever parameters were provided
        call_user_func_array(array('parent', '__construct'), func_get_args());

        // Additional actions that do not need direct access to the parameters
        $arr[] = 'new Item';
    }
}
```

While it makes an interesting exercise, I personally would not recommend actually using this - I think using a separate `init()` method is a much better design.

Comment: I actually like this approach better than the init() approach because it doesn't reinvent constructors.

Comment: It's definitely a bit of a personal preference. For myself, I don't like seeing strings containing method names - it's a bit too `eval`ish, and (IMO) one of the weaknesses of PHP, along with [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), etc.