# Pass constructor arguments to inherited child class

Tags: php, oop

I'm struggling with this for a while now and since Google has [tons of results](https://www.google.nl/search?client=opera&q=php%20oop%20pass%20constructor%20argument%20to%20child%20class&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) on this issue i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong since none of the solutions seems to work for me.

I have two classes `File` and `Image`. I let the `File` class decide wether the input is an image or another type of file. When the file is an image i want to pass that file to the `Image` class to process it.

So far i have this

```
    Class File{
     public $file;

     function __construct($input){
          $this->file = $input;
     }

     public function getFileType(){
          // determine filetype of $this->file
          return 'image';
     }
}

Class Image Extends File{

     function __construct(){}

     public function test(){
          return $this->file;
     }
}

$file = new File('file.jpg');
if($file->getFileType() == 'image'){
     $image = new Image;
     echo $image->test();
}
```

But this doesn't output anything. How can i access the value of the constructor argument of the parent class in the inherited class? Calling `parent::__construct();` in the child constructor class (as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826958/how-do-i-call-the-parent-classes-constructor-with-its-original-parameters-in-php)) gives me a missing argument warning and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603469/php-how-to-pass-child-class-construct-arguments-to-parent-construct) (`call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::__construct'), $args);` in the child constructor) also doesn't work.

What am i missing?

Comment: `$image` and `$file` are __2__ different objects.

Comment: I know, but i thought (based on... well, my assumption) that by making the Image class an extension of the file class i could inherit values from the parent class. Am i wrong on that assumption?

Comment: @Maurice - the issue is that Image is the derived class while File is the parent one. Both classes are objects on their own, where as the child class can access (public) properties / methods of their parent. 

In your case you are trying it the other way around, you are passing things to the PARENT class and trying to access this in the child class, which will not work, because the child class is a different object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to understand that `$image` and `$file` in your code are **2 different** objects.

`$image` knows nothing about `$file` and vice versa.

With your code design the solution can be:

```
Class File {
     public $file;

     function __construct($input){
          $this->file = $input;
     }

     public function getFileType(){
          // determine filetype of $this->file
          return 'image';
     }
}

Class Image Extends File{

     function __construct($input)
     {
         parent::__construct($input);
         // after that you have `$this->file` set
     }

     public function test(){
          return $this->file;
     }
}

$file = new Image('file.jpg');
if ($file->getFileType() == 'image'){
     echo $file->test();
}
```

But such approach is messy. You create object of class `Image` and after creation you make sure that it is really image. I suppose you need to use something like `fabric` pattern and generate object of proper kind in a `File` class.